# Change bgcolor of page

Tags: javascript, html, random, background-color

I'm making a website that every time you visit the home page the background color of the page changed to 1 of 10 colors. Every time I try the code below the page just stays white.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function rand() {
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
if (r == 1) {bgcolor('#000000', 'body');}
if (r == 2) {bgcolor('#FFFFFF', 'body');}
if (r == 3) {bgcolor('#00FF00', 'body');}
if (r == 4) {bgcolor('#FF0000', 'body');}
if (r == 5) {bgcolor('#0000FF', 'body');}
if (r == 6) {bgcolor('#FFFF00', 'body');}
if (r == 7) {bgcolor('#00FFFF', 'body');}
if (r == 8) {bgcolor('#FF00FF', 'body');}
if (r == 9) {bgcolor('#C0C0C0', 'body');}
if (r == 10) {bgcolor('#700000', 'body');}
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="body" onload="rand()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An array would greatly reduce the number of repetitions.

Answer (score 4):

Because `bgcolor` doesn't exists. The correct command is the following:

```
if (r == 1) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';}
```

Or you can also access it by it's CSS name:

```
if (r == 1) {document.body.style['background-color'] = '#000000';}
```

**More here**: http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Change-Background-Color-Style.aspx and here [CSS background color in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like

```
var randomColors = ['#000000','#FFFFFF','#00FF00','#FF0000','#0000FF','#FFFF00','#00FFFF','#FF00FF','#C0C0C0','#700000']
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*randomColors.length));
document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColors[r];​
```

fiddle  ( just keep hitting run )

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/ayhUM/

also, this way, you can keep adding colors, or remove colors into the array

Answer (score 1):

Bgcolor is not a javascript function, try the below:

```
document.body.bgColor = '#000000';
```