# Randomly Changing Backgrounds

Tags: php, javascript, css

Is there a way to create a website where the page background image changes every few seconds automatically? I would like to have about a half dozen images that rotate about every ten seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: that would be ugly, possibly nauseating, and potential hazards to ecliptics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this jquery plugin](http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/). The author has done an implementation where the image on the page reloads. You can put the image in a div that will stay behind all the elements in a page so that it then becomes the background.

Jquery can be downloaded [here](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Great input from everyone and some wonderful ideas. I am going to try them and see which one works best. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. I used the [bgStretcher jQuery plugin](http://www.ajaxblender.com). Worked really well.

Here is an implementation example (in the background) of [a portfolio](http://www.cnash44.com/jqueryportfolio/JQueryPortfolio.html).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bgStretcher({
    images: ['img/Backgrounds/abst.jpg','img/Backgrounds/curvy.jpg','img/Backgrounds/circuits.jpg'], 
    //images: ['img/Backgrounds/space/1.jpg','img/Backgrounds/space/3.jpg','img/Backgrounds/space/4.jpg','img/Backgrounds/space/5.jpg','img/Backgrounds/space/6.jpg','img/Backgrounds/space/7.jpg'], 
    imageWidth: 1024, 
    imageHeight: 768,
    slideShowSpeed: 8000,
    nextSlideDelay: 8000,
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Nash

Comment: Great input from everyone and some wonderful ideas. I am going to try them and see which one works best. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was asked here just a few hours ago:

[Randomly change background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181856/change-bgcolor-of-page)

I have taken answer from there and modified it to your case.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        setInterval("myTimer()",1000);
        return false;
    }

    function myTimer()
    {
       var randomImage = [
'http://onlyhdwallpapers.com/wallpaper/light_gray_suede_anon_delivers_high_resolution_desktop_1500x1500_hd-wallpaper-463812.jpg',
       'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kO0Mq7eCchs/TY6MDA6-KqI/AAAAAAAAAEE/90FlAM_QJLs/s1600/BigGrayBox.jpg',
       'http://test3.jpg']
       var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*randomImage .length));
       var newImage = "url(" + randomImage [r] + ")";
       document.body.style.backgroundImage= newImage ;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="myFunction()">
         <div> Some text </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Great input from everyone and some wonderful ideas. I am going to try them and see which one works best. THANKS!