# Change the background color in my HTML code through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

New to JavaScript and HTML. I'm trying to change the background color in my HTML code through JavaScript.

The only thing that I need to happen is to change the background color on `divMain` below from black to white using only JavaScript and keeping the HTML code the same

```
<style>

#divMain {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:320px;
height:460px;
background-color:black;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body 
onload="body_load();" 
>

<div 
id="divMain">
</div>
```

The only things that I have in the JavaScript code is this:

```
function body_load() {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little bit but I don't see how to change it inside of a div tag. Only how to change the background of the body

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about absolute basics, that you should read up on in some tutorial or other.

Comment: This question has an answer to set it for a specific element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript

Comment: why you need this? you can't modify the bg color with CSS? the link above (answer from @ryanulit ) solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the background of an element, you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("divMain").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

It will change the div-Background to red.
But why do you want to make this with javascript?

Solve it with inline-CSS:

```
<div id="divMain" style="background-color: red"></div>
```

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. thank you!

Comment: there was a spelling-error. I updated it

Comment: `Solve it with HTML` I'd call that *inline CSS*.

Comment: @MarkShimala If the answer worked for you, please accept it. If not, post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("divMain").style.backgroundColor="red"` e.g.