# how to make a background-color on a div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="two">
    <div data-role="content" >

        <div id="pic1"></div>  
  </div>
```

and this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("pic1").setAttribute("background-color","red");
</script>
```

The problem is that my div doesn't get the red color as a background!
What's wrong?

Comment: document.getElementById("pic1").style.backgroundColor = "red";

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS background color in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) on the element, there is no `background-color` *attribute*:

```
document.getElementById("pic1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

---

That said, generally best to style things with CSS and add/remove classes.

Answer (score 2):

T.J. Crowder beat me to it, but just as a demo, if you were hellbent on using `setAttribute`, you could do so like this:

```
document.getElementById("pic1").setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
```

As you see, the css attribute is background-color, not the html attribute.

Comment: Another solution: document.getElementById("pic1").style['background-color'] = 'red';