# How can i set the css background through javascript

Tags: javascript

i am new in JavaScript i want to set the background css through JavaScript how it possible can anyone help me.

```
element.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background property sets or returns up to eight separate background properties, in a shorthand form.

With this property, you can set/return one or more of the following (in any order):

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
background-size
background-origin
background-clip
```

**Example:**

```
object.style.background="color image repeat attachment position size origin clip|initial|inherit"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.style.background = "#f3f3f3 url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top";
```

please check this link also [Style background Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In general, CSS properties are converted to JavaScript by making them camelCase without any dashes. So background-color becomes backgroundColor.

```
function setColor(element, color){
element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

document.bgColor for changing background color

```js
function changeColor(){
  color = document.getElementById("inpu").value;
  
  
  document.bgColor=color;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="red" id="inpu"><button onClick="changeColor()">Color</button>
```